# Data of chemical element ambundance on celestial objects?

Tags: natural-resources, space-industry

For worldbuilding purposes, I'm trying to find data on chemical element abundance on different celestial bodies, and I'm interested in numbers or percentages by mass. I have found something about Earth, but any Wikipedia article about other planets that discuss chemical compositions only lists elements without specifying numbers.

**Is there a source(s) with reliable data on chemical element abundances on different celestial objects?**

I'm mostly interested in what elements and in what quantities could be found on each world to work on how interplanetary & interstellar trade would work.

It would be great to have data on exoplanets, but if not, our own Solar System will suffice; I could then extrapolate.

Comment: From your tags, I assume you're only interested in minerals that are accessible on or near the surface of terrestrial planets. Is that correct? Also, are you just asking about Solar System planets, or are you looking for data on exoplanets?

Comment: For some info on factors affecting the distribution of elements within the Earth, please see https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/144758/123208 & links therein.

Comment: @PM2Ring I don't expect us to have data on exoplanets, but it would be great if we do. If not, Solar System will suffice; I would then just extrapolate.
Also, I have decided to widen my hunt on the whole elemental table and all celestial objects, including asteroids and black hole accretion disks.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abundance_of_the_chemical_elements#Universe has tables & a graph of element abundances, but it (mostly) ignores the problem of distribution. We can use Earth-based distribution models, to an extent, on terrestrial planets. However, water is an extremely important factor in those models, so such models require severe modification when applied to planets like Mercury.

Comment: Asteroids are good, since with sufficient technology you can access all the minerals of a small asteroid. Small asteroids tend to be homogeneous, but larger asteroids (and planetesimals) are not, as I mention here: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/49425/16685

Comment: Forget about mining accretion discs. Active black holes are very dangerous. In comparison, extracting minerals from the lava of an erupting volcano while someone is dropping H-bombs on you would be child's play. ;)

Comment: @PM2Ring "...but it (mostly) ignores the problem of distribution." If you mean distribution on planets/planetoids' surfaces, that I don't care. I'm looking for which celestial objects have which elements and how many to work out how mining and interplanetary/interstellar trade would function. I started with metal ores, assuming that metals are easiest to transport across large distances (they don't rot and decay nor go out of fashion).

Comment: I'm mainly talking about how the element is distributed through the body of the planet. Eg, a planet might have a lot of gold, but it's useless if it's almost all in the core, with only tiny traces of gold uniformly distributed through the crust. However, surface distribution is important, too. We normally extract minerals from concentrated ore bodies. It's generally not cost-effective to grind up large amounts of random crust material and separate it into its component elements. But this is getting rather off-topic for Space Exploration...

Comment: What is a celestial object in your opinion? If the Sun and stars are celestial objects, information about chemical elements within them is delivered by spectral analysis.

Comment: @Uwe, for the purpose of this question - minable celestial objects.

Comment: Although element abundance in the star would correlate with element abundance in orbiting celestial objects, right?